# EF-6.x Error "A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column"

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I got stuck with a EF 6.x configuration for a seamingly simple relationship :-(. I hope that someone can help me here!

Here the description:

1. 'Network' may have a 'Production', 'Production' must have a 'Network' (1 : 0..1)
2. 'Network' and 'Production' do have to have individual PKs
3. 'Production' being the Dependant in this relationship does howevern need its PK for other relationship configurations

The classes are defined as follows:

```
public class Network
{
  public int NetworkId {get; set;}
  :
  public int? ProductionId {get;set;}
  public virtual Production Production {get;set;}
  :
}

public class Production
{
   public int ProductionId {get;set;}
   :
   public int NetworkId {get;set;}
   public virtual Network {get;set;}
   :
}
```

the accompanying configurations are:

```
public NetworkMap ()
{
   HasKey (p => p.NetworkId).Property (p => p.NetworkId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption (DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
   HasOptional (p => p.Production).WithRequired (p => p.Network);
}

public ProductionLineMap ()
{
   HasKey (p => p.ProductionLineId)
           .Property (p => p.ProductionId)
           .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption (DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
}
```

if I try to save a 'Production' I get the follwoing error:

```
XPRD.Location.Data.Exceptions.XPRDDbException : DbException
  ----> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException : An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  ----> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException : An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  ----> System.InvalidOperationException : A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'ProductionId'.
```

Somehow I understand that the problem is connected with 'ProductionId' but I don't know how to write the configuration or alter the class definition in order to achieve what I want.

I'd be greatful for any help!

Cheers,
Peter